# Do I need to subclass the Image&Text NSTableCellView to add a label?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a view-based NSTableView (using the Image&Text CellView).

Depending on the dataItems in the dataSource, I select an appropriate CellView to display them.

One of the templates has an additional (to the default CellView) label on it. But I don't know what is the right way to access it when I instantiate the CellView (I need to set label's value).

My question basically is - should I search for the subview (like in the following snippet) or should I subclass the CellView, add a property and so on?

```
    NSArray* subviews = [cellView subviews];
    for (id view in subviews) {
        ViewType* view = (ViewType*)view;
        if ( view != nil ) {
            if ( [view.identifier isEqualToString:@"idSetInIB"] ) {
                [view setStringValue:dataItem.someValue];
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The Apple TableView Programming guide gives good basic examples on how to subclass NSTableCellView for a view based table.

It's probably a little easier to do without bindings. 
And certainly better for learning it.

However, you should be able to just add another text field in Interface Builder to the table cell view.

Read the guide. It will help tremendously.

Comment: Here is what the guide is saying about the hierarchy of views: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html

They just mention the subviews method, there is a guide for subclassing NSView, but what I try to find out is - which way is the correct one when the case is as simple as explained above (adding a label in a CellView).

Comment: If you think the answer to my question is - definitely subclassing is the way to go - please edit your answer.

Comment: If you read the guide you will understand that subclassing is the intended way to work with view based tables.